# Getting variable from session storage in Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, python-requests

I'm trying to simulate browser post request using python requests module.
The problem is that I don't know how to get one variable that browser is getting from javascript (don't have any knowledge in it) of the site. Here is this part:

```
t.userid = Storages.sessionStorage.get("user").id
```

Is there any way I can get it?

P.S. As I understand that variable is stored in the session storage, and I am not sure if it is possible to get through requests, may be I should use selenium to get it? If yes how I can do that?

Comment: What is that code? How does it relate to anything? What is `t`, and what does it do with `userId`? What are you trying to do? What should the result be?

Comment: There is javascript code that forming post request, I'm trying to simulate it. I have all variables except one (userid) and code above is forming that variable, that is what I have found in that javascript. More code from that function to undestand what is 't': function l(e) {
            var t = {},
                u = cleanFileName(e.name);
            t.video = e, t.name = u, t.userid = Storages.sessionStorage.get("user").id, ...

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution.
I got this variable using selenium:

```
driver.execute_script("return sessionStorage.getItem('user');");
```